# Remove related object from list C++

Tags: c++, list, oop

I have some code:

```
class LowLevelObject {
    public:
    void* variable;
};

// internal, can't get access, erase, push. just exists somewhere
std::list<LowLevelObject*> low_level_objects_list;


class HighLevelObject {
    public:
    LowLevelObject* low_level_object;
};

// my list of objects
std::list<HighLevelObject*> high_level_objects_list;

// some callback which notifies that LowLevelObject* added to low_level_objects_list.
void CallbackAttachLowLevelObject(LowLevelObject* low_level_object) {
    HighLevelObject* high_level_object = new HighLevelObject;
    high_level_object->low_level_object = low_level_object;
    low_level_object->variable = high_level_object;
    high_level_objects_list.push_back(high_level_object);
}

void CallbackDetachLowLevelObject(LowLevelObject* low_level_object) {
    // how to delete my HighLevelObject* from high_level_objects_list?
    // HighLevelObject* address in field `variable` of LowLevelObject.
}
```

I have low level object which defined in library, it contains field `variable` for using by user.
I set to this `varaible` pointer to my `HighLevelObject` from my code.
I can set callbacks on add and remove `LowLevelObject` from list in library.
But how can I remove my `HighLevelObject` from my list of objects?
Of course, I know that I can iterate whole list and find by object by pointer and remove, but it's long way.
List may contains a lot of objects.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: "_Of course, I know that I can iterate whole list and find by object by pointer and remove, but it's long way._" It's `std::list`. Any algorithm will need to iterate through the list to find the item to remove, even if such iteration wouldn't be explicit, from your point of view.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Not really. The OP has control of _their_ list. There are plenty of ways to replace that with some other structure that can index the data to provide fast lookup for the required use cases.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Which was exactly my point - as long as it is `std::list` - you can't do better, than search by iteration.

Comment: You create a `new HighLevelObject` when a low level object is attached. Symmetry would call for that object to be `delete`d when the low level object is detached, but this step is not present in `CallbackDetachLowLevelObject`. Should it be there?

Comment: Here's a simple way to figure out how to do this, and it never fails to work. Just take out a blank sheet of paper. Write down using short, simple sentences in plain English, a step-by-step process of doing this. When done, [call your rubber duck for an appointment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). We don't write code for other people, on Stackoverflow. We always refer such questions to your rubber duck. After your rubber duck approves your proposed plan of action, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++. Mission accomplished!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setup lends itself to finding a solution where converting a pointer to an iterator is a constant-time operation. [Boost.Intrusive offers this feature.](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/intrusive/obtaining_iterators_from_values.html) This will require changes to your code though; if you were not careful about encapsulation, these changes might be significant. A `boost::intrusive::list` is functionally similar to a `std::list`, but requires some changes to your data structure. This option might not be for everyone.

Another feature of Boost.Intrusive is that sometimes you do not need to explicitly convert a pointer to an iterator. If you enable auto-unlinking, then the actual deletion from the list happens behind the scenes in a destructor. This is not a good option if you need to get the size of your list in constant time, though. (Nothing in the question indicates that getting the size of the list is needed, so I'll go ahead with this approach.)

If you had a container of objects, I might let you work through the documentation for the intrusive list. However, your use of pointers makes the conversion potentially confusing, so I'll walk through the setup. The setup begins with the following.

```
#include <boost/intrusive/list.hpp>

// Shorten the needed boost namespace.
namespace bi = boost::intrusive;
```

Since the list of high-level objects contains pointers, an auxiliary structure is needed. We need what amounts to a pointer that derives from a class provided by Boost. (I will proceed assuming that the objects created in `CallbackAttachLowLevelObject()` must be destroyed in `CallbackDetachLowLevelObject()`. Hence, I've changed the raw pointer to a smart pointer.)

```
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

// The auxiliary structure that will be stored in the high level list:
// The hook supplies the intrusive infrastructure.
// The link_mode enables auto-unlinking.
class ListEntry :  public bi::list_base_hook< bi::link_mode<bi::auto_unlink> >
{
public:
    // The expected way to construct this.
    explicit ListEntry(std::unique_ptr<HighLevelObject> && p) : ptr(std::move(p)) {}
    // Another option would be to forward parameters for constructing HighLevelObject,
    // and have the constructor call make_unique. I'll leave that as an exercise.
    
    // Make this class look like a pointer to HighLevelObject.
    const std::unique_ptr<HighLevelObject> & operator->() const { return ptr; }
    HighLevelObject& operator*() const { return *ptr; }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<HighLevelObject> ptr;
};
```

The definition of the list becomes the following. We need to specify non-constant time `size()` to allow auto-unlinking.

```
bi::list<ListEntry, bi::constant_time_size<false>> high_level_objects_list;
```

These changes require some changes to the "attach" callback. I'll present them before going on to the "detach" callback.

```
// Callback that notifies when LowLevelObject* is added to low_level_objects_list.
void CallbackAttachLowLevelObject(LowLevelObject* low_level_object) {
    // Dynamically allocate the entry, in addition to allocating the high level object.
    ListEntry * entry = new ListEntry(std::make_unique<HighLevelObject>());
    (*entry)->low_level_object = low_level_object; // Double indirection needed here.
    low_level_object->variable = entry;
    high_level_objects_list.push_back(*entry);     // Intentional indirection here!
}
```

With this prep work, the cleanup is in your destructors, as is appropriate for RAII. Your "detach" just has to initiate the process. One line suffices.

```
void CallbackDetachLowLevelObject(LowLevelObject* low_level_object) {
    delete static_cast<ListEntry *>(low_level_object->variable);
}
```

---

There (appropriately) is not enough context in the question to explain why the high level list is of pointers instead of being of objects. One potential reason is that the high-level object is polymorphic, and the use of pointers avoids slicing. If this is the case (or if there is not a good reason for using pointers), an intrusive list could be designed with less impact on existing code. The caveat here is that changes to `HighLevelObject` are required.

The initial setup is the same as before.

```
#include <boost/intrusive/list.hpp>

// Shorten the needed boost namespace.
namespace bi = boost::intrusive;
```

Next, have `HighLevelObject` derive from the hook.

```
class HighLevelObject : public bi::list_base_hook< bi::link_mode<bi::auto_unlink> > {
    public:
    LowLevelObject* low_level_object;
};
```

In this situation, the list is of `HighLevelObject`s, not of pointers, nor of pointer stand-ins.

```
bi::list<HighLevelObject, bi::constant_time_size<false>> high_level_objects_list;
```

The "attach" callback reverts to almost what is in the question. The one change to this function is that the object itself is pushed into the list, not a pointer. This is why slicing is not a problem; it's not a copy that is added to the list, but the object itself.

```
    high_level_objects_list.push_back(*high_level_object);  // Intentional indirection!
```

The rest of your code might work as-is. We just need the "detach" callback, which again is a one-liner.

```
void CallbackDetachLowLevelObject(LowLevelObject* low_level_object) {
    delete static_cast<HighLevelObject *>(low_level_object->variable);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for those who do not want to use – or cannot use – Boost.Intrusive.

As long as modifying `HighLevelObject` is an option, the object could be told how to remove itself from the list. Add a callback to `HighLevelObject` and invoke it in its destructor.

```
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

class HighLevelObject {
    public:
    LowLevelObject* low_level_object;

    // ******  The above is from the question. The below is new. ******

    // Have the destructor invoke the callback.
    ~HighLevelObject() { if ( on_delete ) on_delete(); }

    // Provide a way to set the callback.
    void set_deleter(std::function<void()> && deleter)
    { on_delete = std::move(deleter); }
    
    private:
    // Storage for the callback:
    std::function<void()> on_delete;
};
```

Set the callback when an object is added to the high level list.
*Caution:* This setup supports only one callback. Don't overwrite the callback somewhere else in your code!
*Caution:* Additional precautions are needed if multiple threads might add elements to `high_level_objects_list`.

```
// Callback that notifies when LowLevelObject* is added to low_level_objects_list.
void CallbackAttachLowLevelObject(LowLevelObject* low_level_object) {
    HighLevelObject* high_level_object = new HighLevelObject;
    high_level_object->low_level_object = low_level_object;
    low_level_object->variable = high_level_object;
    high_level_objects_list.push_back(high_level_object);

    // ******  The above is from the question. The below is new. ******

    // Arrange cleanup.
    auto iter = high_level_objects_list.end();  //  Not thread-safe
    high_level_object->set_deleter([iter]() { high_level_objects_list.erase(iter); });
}
```

With this prep work, the cleanup is in your destructor, as is appropriate for RAII. Your "detach" just has to initiate the process. One line suffices.

```
void CallbackDetachLowLevelObject(LowLevelObject* low_level_object) {
    delete static_cast<HighLevelObject *>(low_level_object->variable);
}
```

---

I was thinking of storing an iterator (specifically, `iter` in the above) in `HighLevelObject` and having the destructor use that to call `erase()` instead of going through a lambda. However, I ran into trouble with the declarations, since members of `std::list` cannot be instantiated with an incomplete element type. It could be done with type erasure, but at that point I preferred using a function object.